# What Joomla 3.x Legacy?

Tags: joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.x. there is a folder on libraries/legacy. Where there are folder like 'model', 'controller', 'application'. What is the purpose of that folder? I am very much new in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions which are still in the older legacy version, like Joomla 2.x or joomla 1.x. The controllers, and Models of current version may be significantly different than the previsions versions. Having the legacy folder ( which contains older version of Model and Controller)  is a good idea since the old extensions using the older Controller now can change their Controller classes extends to JControllerLegacy ) and still able to run in the current version of Joomla. So this requires very minimal change than conforming to the newer version of JContorller or JModel for that matter.